# Десериализация поврежденных данных json.net

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

Использую библиотеку newtonsoft json.net. В файле у меня хранится коллекция json объектов. Допустим у нас есть поврежденная json строка в одном из объектов, например:

```
{
   "PublicationDate": "1999-04-14T00:00:00",
   !error!,
   "Authors": ["Vasya","Dima"],
   "Location": "Moscow"
}
```

Могу ли я как-нибудь пропустить данный объект и перейти к парсингу следующего?

Comment: Ого, хороший вопрос.

Comment: Я пробую наследоваться от JsonConverter, создаю экземпляр, передаю его в DeserializeObject<>(json, CorruptedJsonConverter). Но переопределенные методы даже не вызываются

Comment: Я попробовал так: https://pastebin.com/0h5Y0HVB, но непонятно, как восстанавливать чтение в случае исключения.

Comment: Пробовал восстанавливаться так: https://pastebin.com/RUpGny24, но `JsonTextReader` не хочет читать из середины текста.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Данные в некорректном формате **не должны** обрабатываться. Данные в некорректном формате JSON — это данные **не в формате JSON**.

### Правильный способ

Почините то, что выдаёт вам некорректные данные.

### Костыльный способ

Если вы не можете починить источник, то конвертируйте данные в корректный формат.

1. Если ошибка очень простая, например, некоторые элементы принимают вид `!error!`, как в вашем примере, то можно натравить на исходную строку регулярное выражение.
2. Если ошибка сложная, то и решение сложное. Возьмите класс, разбирающий лексемы JSON из JSON.NET (`JsonTextReader`), модифицируйте под ожидаемую грамматику. Унаследоваться не получится, потому что весь важный код приватен. Придётся копипастить.

**@VladD** и другие пытаются найти обходные пути для "игнорирования" ошибки, но этот путь тупиковый, потому что для лексера нет выхода из состояния "ошибка". В этом состоянии он не знает, где он находится, и что следует дальше.

Comment: Ну это да, я поговорил с коллегами, и никто не придумал хорошего, надёжного метода восстановления. Разве что ориентируюсь на синтаксическую структуру _конкретного_ документа (простой пример: каждая запись располагается с новой строки).

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonStr, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                Error = (sender, args) =>
                {
                    args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Я пробовал такой же код, у меня возвращается пустая коллекция.

Comment: У меня тоже возвращается пустая коллекция